# Power series of $\frac{(1-qx)^k}{(1-qx)^{k+1}-(px)^{k+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, fractions

I need to expand the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{(1-qx)^k}{(1-qx)^{k+1}-(px)^{k+1}},\quad p>0,\;q>0,\;p+q=1
$$
into a power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_n x^n.
$$
$k$ is an integer $>1$.

The only thing that comes to my mind is the Taylor series expansion, but here it does not inspire enthusiasm. Maybe there is some nice way?

*Edit:* Following the Ted Shifrin's hint, I got the product of the sums of geometric series
$$
\frac{(1-qx)^k}{(1-qx)^{k+1}-(px)^{k+1}}=\frac1{1-qx}\cdot
\frac1{1-\left( \frac{px}{1-qx} \right)^{k+1}};
$$
Then,
$$
\frac1{1-qx}= 1+qx+q^2x^2+\ldots
$$
$$
\frac1{1-\left( \frac{px}{1-qx} \right)^{k+1}}=
1+\left( \frac{px}{1-qx} \right)^{k+1}+
\left( \frac{px}{1-qx} \right)^{2(k+1)}+\ldots
$$
$$
\left( \frac{px}{1-qx} \right)^{m(k+1)}= 
px^{m(k+1)}\frac1{\left( 1-qx \right)^{m(k+1)}}= 
px^{m(k+1)}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-m(k+1)}{n} q^n x^n
$$
This is great progress, but it seems to me that this is not the end. It’s not for nothing that it’s given $p+q=1$. Does this somehow make things easier?

Comment: Does it help to factor $a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}$?

Comment: Perhaps factor out $(1-qx)^{k+1}$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I don't see how this can help

Comment: It looks like you get a product of geometric series, although one needs to be manipulated: $(\frac{px}{1-qx})^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac{(1-q x)^k}{(1-q x)^{k+1}-(p x)^{k+1}}$$
$$\frac 1{f(x)}=1-qx-p x \left(\frac {px}{1-qx}\right)^k$$

$$\left(\frac {px}{1-qx}\right)^k=(px)^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \binom{-k}{n}q^n \,x^n$$ So, the reciprocal of $f(x)$ is simple.

Now, have fun with the long division.

If you use it for
$$g_k(x)=\frac{(1-q x)^k}{(1-q x)^{k+1}-(p x)^{k+1}}$$ and you expand them to $O(x^{k+3})$, you have the simple
$$g_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{k} (qx)^n+(p^{k+1}+q^{k+1})\,x^{k+1}+q\big((k+2)p^{k+1}+q^{k+1}\big)\,x^{k+2}+O(x^{k+3})$$ The next term would be more than nasty.

Answer (score 2):

We show the following power series expansions are valid for non-negative integer $k\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{(1-qx)^k}{(1-qx)^{k+1}-(px)^{k+1}}}
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i j }{k+1}}p+q\right)^n\right)x^n}\\
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k+1}\right\rfloor}
\binom{n}{(k+1)l}p^{(k+1)l}q^{n-(k+1)l}\right)x^n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The key to get (1) is a partial fraction decomposition.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f_k(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{(1-qx)^k}{(1-qx)^{k+1}-(px)^{k+1}}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{(1-qx)-e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{k+1}}px}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{1-\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{k+1}}p+q\right)x}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i j }{k+1}}p+q\right)^nx^n}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^n
> \binom{n}{l}e^{\frac{2\pi i j l}{k+1}}p^lq^{n-l}x^n\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{l}p^lq^{n-l}
> \frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i l}{k+1}}\right)^j\right)x^n\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{l=0}\atop{k+1|l}}^n\binom{n}{l}p^lq^{n-l}\right)x^n\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k+1}\right\rfloor}
> \binom{n}{(k+1)l}p^{(k+1)l}q^{n-(k+1)l}\right)x^n}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows from (3) and (7).

*Comment:*

- In (2) we perform a partial fraction decomposition. Some details: We set
  \begin{align*}
  z:=1-qx,\qquad z_0:=px,\qquad \omega_j:=e^{\frac{2\pi i j }{k+1}}\quad 0\leq j\leq k
  \end{align*}
  we can then write $f_k(x)$ as
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{z^k}{z^{k+1}-z_0^{k+1}}
  =\frac{c_0}{z-z_0}+\frac{c_1}{z-\omega_1 z_0}+\cdots +\frac{c_k}{z-\omega_k z_0}
  \end{align*}
  with unknowns $c_j, 0\leq j\leq k$. We use the decomposition in the *[form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure)*:
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}=\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{P\left(\omega_j z_0\right)}{Q^{\prime}\left(\omega_j z_0\right)}\,\frac{1}{z-\omega_j z_0}
  \end{align*}
  and we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\frac{z^k}{z^{k+1}-z_0^{k+1}}}
  &=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\left(\omega_j z_0\right)^k}{(k+1)\left(\omega_j z_0\right)^k}\,\frac{1}{z-\omega_j z_0}\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{z-\omega_j z_0}}
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we make a geometric series expansion.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we make some rearrangements.
- In (6) we make a simplification by noting that
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i l}{k+1}}\right)^j
  =\begin{cases}
  1\qquad& k+1|l\\
  0\qquad&\mathrm{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
- In (7) we take from the inner sum only summands with indices $l$ being a multiple of $k+1$, since other summands do not contribute.